# NextJS SCRIPT1028 - caused by destructuring in object in Edge

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, next.js

I know there is topic on why this error occurs on here. My question is how to fix it in the NextJS environment and babel to produce chunks that don't include the spread operator in an object. Here is the background.

I need to support Edge18 where the [spread operator is not supported in object destructing](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_operators_spread_spread_in_destructuring). It produces the error:

> SCRIPT1028: SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number

The error is caused by this line:

```
filter(e=>"0"!==t[e]).reduce((e,r)=>({...e,[`-${r}`]:(0,f.default
```

And in particular the `...e`

This code is in a NextJS chunk loaded via

```
<script src="/_next/static/chunks/269073627ff2c2dabb405b46af9d15fd8bf75a34.ed77311839e33222ab61.js" async=""></script>
```

How do I update the babel config to stop using the spread operator (ES2018) in an object? I am using typescript but the `tsConfig` target is `ES5`. I checked the `browserslist` per the Babel documentation for `@babel/preset-env` which links to [browserslist](https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist) and recommends using `npx browserslist` to see the target browsers for a project and Edge 18 is in there.

I do have a custom babel config per the [docs here](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/customizing-babel-config) which follows the docs:

```
{
  "presets": ["next/babel"],
  "plugins": []
}
```

which has an added plugin that configures Styled Components for SSR. That's the only change. I appreciate any pointers in how to get NextJS to produce Chunks that don't contain the spread operator in an object or targets less than ES2018.

---

Edit: Here is package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "3.0.0-beta.50",
    "@apollo/link-context": "^2.0.0-beta.3",
    "@apollo/react-ssr": "^4.0.0-beta.1",
    "@next/bundle-analyzer": "^9.4.4",
    "@sentry/browser": "^5.15.5",
    "@sentry/node": "^5.15.5",
    "@zeit/next-source-maps": "0.0.3",
    "downloadjs": "^1.4.7",
    "framer-motion": "^1.11.0",
    "geolib": "^3.3.1",
    "geomagnetism": "^0.1.0",
    "graphql": "^14.6.0",
    "html-to-image": "^0.1.1",
    "import": "0.0.6",
    "leaflet": "^1.6.0",
    "local-storage": "^2.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "mgrs": "^1.0.0",
    "next": "^9.4.4",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "^4.2.1",
    "react": "0.0.0-experimental-33c3af284",
    "react-dom": "0.0.0-experimental-33c3af284",
    "react-icons": "^3.10.0",
    "react-leaflet": "^2.7.0",
    "react-spinners": "^0.8.3",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.4.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.1.1",
    "uuid": "^7.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@graphql-codegen/add": "^1.15.0",
    "@graphql-codegen/cli": "^1.15.0",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript": "^1.15.0",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript-operations": "^1.15.0",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript-react-apollo": "^1.15.0",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript-resolvers": "^1.15.0",
    "@sentry/webpack-plugin": "^1.11.1",
    "@types/downloadjs": "^1.4.2",
    "@types/little-loader": "^0.2.0",
    "@types/local-storage": "^1.4.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.154",
    "@types/node": "^14.0.6",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.35",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.8",
    "@types/react-leaflet": "^2.5.1",
    "@types/react-transition-group": "~4.2.4",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.0",
    "@types/styled-jsx": "^2.2.8",
    "@types/uuid": "^7.0.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^3.0.2",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.1.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.20.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.0.4",
    "mapkit-typescript": "^5.18.2",
    "postcss-preset-env": "^6.7.0",
    "prettier": "^2.0.5",
    "tailwindcss": "^1.4.6",
    "typescript": "^3.9.3"
  }
```

Edit 2: Here is the package analyzer of the package the chunk that is causing the issue (chunk ID is different because it's from development - same code found in here though)

[image: Chunk analyzer]

---

Edit 3: I think the issue was `tailwindcss`. If I do the accepted solutions answer for `tailwindcss` an es-check `es-check es6 'out/_next/static/chunks/*.js'` returns the `node_modules` chunk as es6 compliant. If I then remove the transpire from the config, it marks the chunk as non es6 compliant at the same code that was erring in original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your dependencies is not using ES5-compliant code for older browsers and will need to be transpiled.

You need to narrow which dependency is producing this code and transpile it using babel. This dependency can be the result of a sub-dependency to a main dependency, so you may have to traverse the **entire dependency tree** all the way down to find the culprit. A simple example would be: [@nivo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nivo) is a React charting package that has a sub-dependency called [d3-scale](https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3-scale) which [dropped support for IE11](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/releases/tag/v3.0.0) and can't be [polyfilled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Polyfill#:~:text=A%20polyfill%20is%20a%20piece,do%20not%20natively%20support%20it.), therefore it needs to be transpiled by babel to work in IE11:

**next.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  webpack(config, { defaultLoaders, isServer }) {
    /* adds a custom Webpack rule for babel to transpile d3-scale */
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.js$/,
      loader: defaultLoaders.babel,
      include: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/](d3-scale)[\\/]/,
    });

    /* return new config to next */
    return config;
  }
};
```

Alternatively, you can use the [next-transpile-modules](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-transpile-modules) package that does the same thing as the above.

Comment: I just added the dependency. I searched my node_modules folder for the offending string, the only thing that appeared was close (but I don't think it) lives in node_modules/next/dist/compiled/find-up. Do you have a recommendation on how to identify which package is the culprit?

Comment: Unfortunately, no easy solution other than either looking for identifiable code-patterns (like naming) or starting from a base boilerplate and adding each dependency/component until the error occurs. Next doesn't make it easy because it polyfills a lot of ES6 syntax in a production build, so using something like [es-check](https://github.com/dollarshaveclub/es-check#get-started) may narrow it down, but perhaps not enough.

Comment: I'm trying to run through it now with es-check - not a lot of luck. I found the chunk that was causing the issue web analyzer and posted it.

Comment: I'm starting to think it is tailwindcss

Comment: I know from experience it shouldn't be coming from `@babel/runtime/helpers`,  `lodash`, `styled-components`, `styled-jsx`, `@emotion`, `hoist-non-react-statics`, `process`, and `uuid`. The rest are components I haven't worked with.

Comment: On a side note, it looks like you're also importing the entre lodash library which isn't necessary. You can reduce the size by either directly importing the function you want `import get from "lodash/get"` or by using their standalone packages: `npm i lodash.get -S` and `import get from "lodash.get"`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215850/discussion-between-diesel-and-matt-carlotta).